# Server external connection refused

Tags: apache, wamp, port, tcp, portforwarding

I am currently using WampServer 3.04, I can connect to it using my local network IP without any problem, but when it comes to connect via the Internet I always get this response: **Connection REFUSED!**

I have done a lot of things:

- Enable Incoming Connections on my firewall for the port **8080** (The port that I want to use)
- Configured HTTPD and HTTPD-vhosts both on my current IP and the port
- Enabled port forward from extenal 8080 to private 8080 to my computer IP
- Enabled put Online on Wamp
- Tested if my port 8080 is open and it is open.

I honestly do not have anything else to try.

My httpd-vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080> 
    ServerName 192.168.1.3 
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www 
    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/"> 
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All 
        Allow from all 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Lets see your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

Comment: My httpd-vhosts#
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:8080>
 ServerName 192.168.1.3
 DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
 <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
  Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: First try changing `Allow from all` to `Require all granted` this is Apache 2.4 syntax

Comment: Yes I did that but the same thing nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue since port  80 was used by VMware process. Hence I killed VMware process.

Run Powershell (get-process *VM* | stop-process -force)

Use star before &after vm

Start WAMP then goto Apache then -test port 80. If its not working then install Apache service(found below test port 80).It should solve the problem.

Regards,

Aameer